# how to merge row in one column (GridView with merged cells)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

How can I merge employs row  Grid view like the picture in asp.net using c#

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make it by `RowSpan` of GridView .

You can reference with the links below

[GridView: Creating groups and summaries](http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm)

[Implement GridView Grouping: Group similar GridView Rows in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-GridView-Grouping-Group-similar-GridView-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)

[Grouping Data in ASP.NET Gridview Control](http://techbrij.com/grouping-gridview-rows-asp-net)

Hope it's helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2;  rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {  GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];  GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
            for (int cellCount = 1; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count;  cellCount++)
            {    if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
                {     if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)    {       gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                    }    else
                    {      gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =  gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;       gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;    }    }     }
```